# Why is {1, 2, 3} an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"[The equality relation (=) on a set of numbers such as {1, 2, 3} is an equivalence relation.](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/relation/eq_relation/eq_relation.html)"

I know the equality relation = is an equivalence relation in the set of real numbers. Because it can satisfy all three conditions of equivalence relation. (1) x=x, reflexive (2) x=y ⇒ y=x symmetric, (3) x=y∧y=z ⇒x=z, transitive

But what does {1, 2, 3} have have to do with equality relation (=), which is an equivalence relation?

Comment: It is kind of an arbitrary remark. I think its purpose is to show that you can define equivalence relations on any set (you don't have to take $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, but you can take a finite set you define yourseld).

Comment: I think you're just reading it incorrectly. The set $\{1,2,3\}$ is meant to be an example of a set of numbers rather than an equality relation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are simply parsing the English sentence incorrectly. It is

> [The equality relation (=)] on [a set of numbers such as {1, 2, 3}] is [an equivalence relation].

not

> [The equality relation (=) on a set of numbers] [such as {1, 2, 3}] is [an equivalence relation].

Comment: +1 for being able to precisely trace the source of the OP's misunderstanding and clarifying it very efficiently.

Comment: Let's all just speak Lojban so things like this don't ever happen.

Answer (score 7):

The set $\{1,2,3\}$ is merely an example where it is easy to check that the properties of an equivalence relation hold. The equality relation is an equivalence relation on *any* set, for exactly the reasons you gave.